# What does error 'identifier must be declared' means in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

The task is to write PL/SQL block for entering new employee throw the Oracle database user's dialog to insert data into the table.
I dont really understand what I am missing here:

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
ACCEPT empno PROMPT 'Enter empno: '
ACCEPT ename PROMPT 'Enter ename: '
ACCEPT job PROMPT 'Enter job: '
ACCEPT mgr PROMPT 'Enter mgr: '
ACCEPT sal PROMPT 'Enter sal: '
ACCEPT deptno PROMPT 'Enter deptno: '
DECLARE
empn NUMBER := &empno;
ena VARCHAR(255) := &ename;
ejob VARCHAR(255) := &job;
emgr NUMBER := &mgr;
ehire DATE := Sysdate;
esal NUMBER := &sal;
ecomm NUMBER := null;
edeptno NUMBER := &deptno;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EMP(EMPNO, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO) VALUES (empn, ena, ejob, emgr, ehire, esal, ecomm, edeptno);
END;
```

Error report:
`Error report - ORA-06550: line 3, column 21: PLS-00201: identifier 'ANDREW' must be declared ORA-06550: line 3, column 5: PL/SQL: Item ignored ORA-06550: line 4, column 22: PLS-00201: identifier 'MANAGER' must be declared ORA-06550: line 4, column 6: PL/SQL: Item ignored ORA-06550: line 11, column 17: PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values ORA-06550: line 11, column 5: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s" *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error. *Action:`

Could you explain, what are the mistakes in my code?

I tried the following:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
ACCEPT empno PROMPT 'Enter empno: '
ACCEPT ename PROMPT 'Enter ename: '
ACCEPT job PROMPT 'Enter job: '
ACCEPT mgr PROMPT 'Enter mgr: '
ACCEPT sal PROMPT 'Tneter sal: '
ACCEPT deptno PROMPT 'Enter deptno: '
DECLARE
empn NUMBER := '&empno';
ena VARCHAR(255) := '&ename';
ejob VARCHAR(255) := '&job';
emgr NUMBER := '&mgr';
ehire DATE := Sysdate;
esal NUMBER := '&sal';
ecomm NUMBER := null;
edeptno NUMBER := '&deptno;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EMP(EMPNO, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO) VALUES (empn, ena, ejob, emgr, ehire, esal, ecomm, edeptno);
END;
```

Error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 9, column 19:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "30;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO EMP(EMPNO, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, CO" when expecting one of the following:

   ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
   date <a string literal with character set specification>
   <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
   <an alternatively-quoted string
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
```

Comment: Just to clarify this: There are two things mixing here. `SET` and `ACCEPT` are not PL/SQL. The PL/SQL block starts with `DECLARE`. And even `&empno` inside the block is not valid PL/SQL. What is happening here is that you are using a tool (sqlplus probably) that has commands of its own (the said `SET` and `ACCEPT`) and that works with variables (`&empno` etc.). The tool creates the PL/SQL block by substituting the variables with values. Unfortunately the created PL/SQL block is invalid for the reason Thomas Kirchhoff explains in his answer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I am using sqldeveloper tool, not sql* plus. My groupmate said it is not needed to use sql* plus to solve this problem

Comment: Oracle's SQL Develoer uses sqlplus internally. The commands and the variable substitution are sql*plus things. This also means that you have used sqlplus without noticing. A pure PL/SQL solution would be a procedure that accepts parameters instead of an anonymous PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution variables are replaced using your input.
For example, becomes:

```
ena VARCHAR(255) := &ename;

ena VARCHAR(255) := ANDREW;
```

And here is the error. Single quotes are missing.

So correct would be:

```
ena VARCHAR(255) := '&ename';
```

You should also specify the data type and the format mask. For example:

```
ACCEPT esal NUMBER FORMAT '999.99'
ACCEPT hired DATE FORMAT 'dd/mm/yyyy'
```

Comment: Thank you, when I try, I will write you feedback here